# 1D vector from lower part of diagonal in matrix [Python]

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matrix, scipy

I am struggeling with pretty easy thing but unfortunatelly I cannot solve it. I have a matrix 64x64 elements as you can see on the image. Where reds are zeros and greens are values I am interested in.

[image]

I would like to end up with only lower triangular part under diagonal (green values) into one array.

I use Python 2.7

Thank you a lot,

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can pull your data into a numpy array, use the `tril_indices` function. It looks like your data doesn't include the main diagonal so you can shift by -1

```
data = np.arange(4096).reshape(64, 64)
inds = np.tril_indices(64, -1) 
vals = data[inds]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.tril_indices` which returns the indices of a lower triangular part of a matrix with given shape, the indices can be further used to extract values from the matrix, suppose your matrix is called `arr`:

```
arr[np.tril_indices(n=64,m=64)]
```

You can provide an extra offset parameter if you want to exclude the diagonal:

```
arr[np.tril_indices(n = 64, m = 64, k = -1)]
```

---

An example:

```
arr = np.array([list(range(i, 5+i)) for i in range(5)])
arr
#array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
#       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
#       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
#       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])

arr[np.tril_indices(n = 5, m = 5)]
# array([0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Answer (score 0):

Two time faster than `triu` on this example :

```
np.concatenate([arr[i,:i] for i in range(1,n)])
```